# Virtual function is called after Vtable is deleted

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Why is it giving a segmentation fault? It seems like the virtual table is deleted and then the user tries to call the function which looks absurd.

```
class base
{
    char *basep;
    public:

    // deep copy exist in copy constructor

    virtual char * fun()
    {
        cout << "fun from drive";
        return basep;
    }
    virtual ~base()
    {
        if(basep) { delete basep; }
        char *temp = fun();
    }
};

class derive : public base
{
    char *derived;
    public:
    // deep copy exist in the copy constructor of derived also
    virtual char *fun()
    {
        cout << "fun from drive";
        return derived;
    }
    ~derive()
    {
        if(derived) { delete derived; }
    }
};

int main()
{
    base *obj = new base;
    delete obj;
}
```

Comment: You have an equally worrisome problem on the line before. This is littered with undefined behavior. Ex: ask yourself what value `basep` has when the destructor for `base` fires. Now consider this, a 64bit OS with 64bit linear pointers has  2^64 possible bit patterns for a data pointer. **One** of them will answer `false` to `if(basep)`. Dunno if you're a gambler, but those odds stink. The same problem exists in `derived`.

Comment: if you call fun() in base's destructor, derive has already been destroyed, therefore you calling fun() is probably a bad idea (or it's undefined behaviour or I don't know).